# Enabling and disabling community server status using Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I can't figure out how to enable or disable [community server status](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047132851-Enabling-Your-Community-Server) with a command command, if anyone could help me i would love it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Call the [Guild#edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.edit) function with the `community` parameter.